# Why is the SearchBoxEx scopes drop-down displaying duplicates?

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-enterprise, search-scope

We have a SearchBoxEx control defined as follows:

```
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx SearchResultPageURL="/Pages/SearchResults.aspx" id="searchControl" RegisterStyles="false" DropDownMode="ShowDD_NoContextual_DefaultURL" TextBeforeDropDown="" TextBeforeTextBox="" TextBoxWidth="150" GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch15.png" GoImageActiveUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch15.png" UseSiteDefaults="false" SuppressWebPartChrome="true" runat="server" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{0BA04967-6A1C-49F3-8F58-F129878DCD9B}" ScopeDisplayGroupName="Search Dropdown"/>
```

We also have Shared Scopes set up in the Search Service Application, which are then arranged into the appropriate Display Groups under each Site Collection.

We have four site collections in the following locations:

```
 1. http://site/
 2. http://site/subsite/two
 3. http://site/subsite/three
 4. http://site/subsite/four
```

The problem we have is that in the Scopes drop-down next to the search box, the Scopes are duplicated as follows:

1. Scope 1
2. Scope 2
3. Scope 3
4. Scope 1
5. Scope 2
6. Scope 3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The issue appears to be caused by any modification of the SearchBoxEx object (we're attempting to configure the SearchResultPageURL attribute) in the codebehind during the OnLoad event. Still looking for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today (SP 2010) while setting up a new search-box for a new library that we received a request for (I am green.

```
The List:
=========
This Site: DocumentCenter
Scope A 
Scope B (followed by)
Scope A   
Scope B
```

However there was only a single site collection in this case - so perhaps the fact that you have 4 had no bearing on the issue.

Interestingly enough the matter resolved itself after some time* so perhaps it was a caching issue.

(* 15-30 mins - not for my lack of seeking out a means to solve it but the resolution seemed independent of these efforts)